# WPF optimization: Insert/Delete child from StackPanel

Tags: wpf, user-controls, stackpanel

I often insert/delete 20-30 very complicated UserControls into `StackPanel`.
All UserControls already created and cached for reusing. Before reusing control I clean old parent and remember control.

Operations like `StackPanel.Children.Remove`, `StackPanel.Children.Add` take a lot of time in my scenarios.

How can I optimize these operations? E.g. insert all controls in `StackPanel` at a time or freeze notifications during collection's modifications or else?

May who known useful articles regrading wpf optimization (except MSDN)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the `OnCollectionChanged()` event handler of your `ObservableCollection`, to either disable event handling all together, or to queue the events to handle later.

See the post here, the answer could help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5491534/903056

Comment: How I known StackPanel does't use ObservableCollection for internal implementation. It uses UIElementCollection and I don't have idea how I can customise this collection

Comment: I assumed the items in your StackPanel were bound to an ObservableCollection (as often done in MVVM).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to look into virtualized UI or data loading ( if any) strategies.

In this specific case, use controls like `VirtualizingStackPanel` to make the UI draw fewer things. You can have more information on [this](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=338) blog.

Comment: How I wrote in question, I use only ~20 controls in container. The problem is that my child controls very complicated. And I think that each insertion cause water flow notifications for already inserted controls.